# jSerialComm can't refresh?

Tags: java, swing, serial-port, serial-communication

So currently I have been working on an interesting personal java library that implements jSerialComm. The idea is to receive data over Serial Port, package it up, and broadcast it via. the internet using the java.net library to communicate with devices wirelessly (As long as it is plugged into the server terminal) which the server will most likely turn into a RPi3.

My application so far has been finished as far as the hardwiring serial communication aspect goes, but there is one bug that is driving me nuts. I can connect to the first device flawlessly, but If I choose to disconnect and try to connect to another it just opens the Comm port and does not activate a new instance of the DataListener event so I can't listen for new data.

```
private void btnListenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

            oPort = SerialPort.getCommPort(cmbPortslist.getItemAt(cmbPortslist.getSelectedIndex()));

            if(btnListen.getText() == "Listen") {
            cmbPortslist.enable(false);
            btnListen.setText("Break");
            try {
                oPort.openPort();
                terminalBox.append("Opened : " + oPort.getSystemPortName() + " : " + oPort.getBaudRate() + " Baud\n");
                beginEvent();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                terminalBox.append(e + "\n");
            }
        }
        else {
            oPort.closePort();
            terminalBox.append("Broke connection with : "+ oPort.getSystemPortName() +"\n");
            cmbPortslist.enable(true);
            btnListen.setText("Listen");
        }
}

public void beginEvent() {
    oPort.addDataListener(new SerialPortDataListener() {
        @Override
    public int getListeningEvents() { return SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_AVAILABLE; }
        @Override
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event)
        {
            if (event.getEventType() != SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_AVAILABLE)
                return;
                    try {
                    newData = new byte[oPort.bytesAvailable()]; 
                    int numRead = oPort.readBytes(newData, newData.length);
                    for (byte b : newData) {
                    if((char) b == '@') {
                            terminalBox.append("\n");
                        } else {
                            terminalBox.append(String.valueOf((char) b));
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) { }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: First thing I notice, is `==` for comparing String equality. Don't do that. Use `.equals`.

Comment: I second what @ElliottFrisch states. The reason for the problem is that `==` checks if the two *object references* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The `.equals` and `equalsIgnoreCase` methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.

Comment: `} catch (Exception e) { }` Never do that! It is sticking your head in the sand. Change every instance to `} catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }` (unless something better like logging is implemented). For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).